# How to change the direction of adding new dynamic tabs in ngx-bootstrap Tabs

Tags: angular, dynamic, tabs, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-bootstrap Tabs component with the option for dynamic tabs   (https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_ZKdzKKZ3AIV7JPtCh3tsgIaEAAYASAAEgL8SfD_BwE#/tabs#tabs-dynamic)

The default behavior of the component is every new tab to be added at the right-end of the tab bar.

I'm trying to achieve every new tab to be added at the beginning of the tab bar (at the left-end of the tab bar)
Since this are dynamic tabs and i have the control over the array, I'm already unshifting the new tab at the beginning  of the array. But the Tabs component ignores the order of the tabs in the tab's array and keeps rendering the tabs by pushing the new tab on the right-end of the tab bar.